# Getting specific values from connection string

Tags: c#, winforms

I have string like below;

```
oradb = Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.87.50)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=testdb)));User Id = john; Password=test;
```

I want to get only `'192.168.87.50' , '1521' , 'testdb' , 'john'` from above connection string and put into some textboxes.

I tried to make with regexp and understand that it's not possible with regexp.

How can I do it?

Comment: You could read the ConnectionString in using ConfigurationManager and then load up a System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings class and retrieve what you want using Properties from there?

Comment: @jmb.mage this is winform btw. Also how can i get the specified parameters one by one. Can you please write this as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there should be a more convenient way, you still can use RegExp for this.
Try this code:

```
var input =
    "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.87.50)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=testdb)));User Id = john; Password=test;";


var hostRegx = new Regex("HOST\\s*=\\s*(?<host>[^\\)]+)");
var portRegx = new Regex("PORT\\s*=\\s*(?<port>[^\\)]+)");
var dbRegx = new Regex("SERVICE_NAME\\s*=\\s*(?<db>[^\\)]+)");
var userRegx = new Regex("User Id\\s*=\\s*(?<user>[^;]+)");
var passRegx = new Regex("Password\\s*=\\s*(?<pass>[^;]+)");

var host = hostRegx.Match(input).Groups["host"].Value;
var port = portRegx.Match(input).Groups["port"].Value;
var db = dbRegx.Match(input).Groups["db"].Value;
var user = userRegx.Match(input).Groups["user"].Value;
var pass = passRegx.Match(input).Groups["pass"].Value;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: @johntrue thank you. By the way, I'm think my approach can be optimized, maybe with one huge regex

Answer (score 1):

You can use connection object to retrieve all these information.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); var dbName = connection.Database;
```

For server name:

```
DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
var server = connection.DataSource;
```