# c# Pull multiple matches from text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file coming in that has specific data I would like to pull out for each server. There are 1000's of lines but only a few hundred start with `'server:"`.  For each of those lines i would like to look for the matches of `"HOST="`, `"PORT="` and `"SID="`. I would like to display that values after each of those until the next `")"`.

I'm able to pull only the lines that start with server but I'm not sure how to pull only the values I'm looking for.

Here is a text example:

```
server: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=name.domain)(PORT=number))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sidnumber)
```

Comment: You can slightly modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558691/4685428) answer

Comment: use `Substring`, `IndexOf` ?

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Not sure how I didnt see this example.